theme.palette.mode is wrong in first render
I set up MUI with a <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> where
const theme = createTheme({
  colorSchemes: {
    dark: {...},
    light: {...}
}})

In the child component I tried:
const theme = useTheme();
console.log(theme.palette.mode)

Even though my local storage variable is set to mui-mode=dark this logs light
And I also tried:
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(theme.palette.mode);
  }, [theme.palette.mode]);

Even the effect's first log is light and immediately after dark.
Why can't MUI's ThemeProvider load the mui-mode from localStorage before the first render of its children.
